# Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples. error

Tags: lstm

I want to use the LSTM model to predict the stock price 45 days from now. What number should I put in instead of 5 to predict the stock price after 45 days? I keep getting errors.

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data = scaler.fit_transform(data)

sequence_length = 20  

forecast_days = 5  

X = []
y = []
for i in range(len(data) - sequence_length - forecast_days + 1):
    X.append(data[i:i+sequence_length])
    y.append(data[i+sequence_length:i+sequence_length+forecast_days])

X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

y_train = y_train.reshape(-1, 5 * forecast_days)
y_val = y_val.reshape(-1, 5 * forecast_days)
```

This is the code for trying to predict the stock price in five days